# How to get the ID from a newly inserted row with QSqlQuery and SQLite?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, qt5, qsqlquery

I have a table `T` that has an field `id`, which is an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, and a `INTEGER` field `f`. With Qt5 I insert a row with the following code:

```cpp
QSqlQuery insert;
insert.exec("INSERT INTO T (f) VALUES (0)");
```

But how do I get the `id` of the newly inserted field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`lastInsertId()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId) method of [`QSqlQuery`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html):

```cpp
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database();
if(db.driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::LastInsertId)){
    QSqlQuery insert;
    bool res = insert.exec("INSERT INTO T (f) VALUES (0)");
    Q_ASSERT(res);

    QVariant id = insert.lastInsertId();
    Q_ASSERT(id.isValid() && !id.isNull());
    qDebug() << id.toInt();
}
```

Comment: Where is this `last_id` variable defined?

Comment: @Ramiro I forgot to erase it, I was doing the function test with several insert, in this case it is not necessary